# Intermittent network errors on AX6000 router

Tags: networking, router, ethernet

I am plagued by intermittent disconnects on a TP-Link AX6000 router. I just upgraded it to the latest firmware and... it didn't help. I should emphasize that this is on Ethernet, not on wi-fi - though I am about two meters from the router so I could try wi-fi too, I guess.

This is what the interruptions look like:

[image: PING to router timing out for a few seconds]

While the interruption is usually 4-5 seconds (and happens maybe once an hour), this is enough to drop me out of most online games, which is extremely disruptive. Is there anything anyone can suggest?

Oh - someone (on a different site) said that it might be the cable or the port. I don't think that's likely, because when the connection drops it drops everywhere in the house (my daughter also plays games, and my wife watches TV online - both of them complain at the same time, and one is on a different cable/port and the other one is on a wi-fi connection).

I should mention that I'm a *Windows* programmer, so "install this Linux" will not be a great help unless it's mostly a click-here-and-run thing.

Comment: Does the router have any logs of what it might be doing at those times? There is a chance that it is busy rejecting bad packets such as from malware on the outside.

Comment: You said you updated the firmware. That is normally a good thing to do. Did you / can you Reset the router to Factory values and set it up again?

Comment: Nothing shows up in the log (I kept that page opened and waited for another glitch, which just happened a few seconds ago). I will try resetting the router but it's going to be tomorrow morning (so about 12 hours from now).

Comment: I did that - reset the router to factory defaults - this morning, and everything worked perfectly (I had a few hours of uninterrupted gaming)... and then two minutes ago it happened again. :(